# What does this # line of code mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, actix-web

Im learning rust and I came across this sample code:

```
use actix_web::{middleware, web, App, HttpRequest, HttpServer};

async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> &'static str {
    println!("REQ: {req:?}");
    "Hello world!"
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "actix_web=info");
    env_logger::init();

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            // enable logger
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(web::resource("/index.html").to(|| async { "Hello world!" }))
            .service(web::resource("/").to(index))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

As someone coming from Java, I dont know what this line of code means:

```
#[actix_web::main]
```

If I remove that and run the program, the error says 'main function cannot be async' , so it must be important.

Does anyone have link to documentation explaining what it is - the use of pound (#) sign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html). There are various kinds of attributes. In this case, this is an [proc macro attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#attribute-macros), [`actix_web::main`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/attr.main.html). It takes the item annotated with it (`async fn main()`) and transforms it into some other thing, usually some variation of the original code.

For example, this attribute prepares the Actix runtime and allows you to have an `async` main (in reality, `main()` cannot be async, but this attribute transforms it into something like `fn main() -> ... { actix_web::rt::System::new().block_on(async move { ... }) }`).